# Pasar coleccion de objetos mediante link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenos días, como podría pasar una colección de objetos mediante link_to entre vistas en rails?

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.html_safe, family_group_path(obj), data: {modal: true} %>
```

Comment: Podrías pasar el objeto de la vista al controlador, y luego desde el controlador a la segunda vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un forma sencilla de enviar un objeto desde una vista a otra vista es utilizando el
controller para recibir el objeto en el hash `params[]`, y luego asignarlo a una variable de instancia.

Lo primero es el envíar el objeto desde la vista de origen, se asigna la una variable `obj`, y luego se pasa como parametro
este objeto en forma de hash al path helper

```
#view1.html.erb
<% object = coleccion_objetos %> 
<%= link_to 'texto', family_group_path(obj, :send_object => object) %>
```

Esto hace que esté disponible en el controller en el `params[:send_object]`, por lo que se puede asignar a una variable
de instancia

```
#family_group_controller.rb
def show
    ...
    @send_object = params[:send_object]
end
```

Y finalmente, en la vista de destino se puede hacer uso de la variable de instancia

```
#view2.html.erb
<h2>@send_object: <%= @send_object %> </h2>
```